# MySQL Single Dash Use Instead of an Equal Sign

Tags: mysql, database, syntax

I was just wondering if anyone knew about the difference between:

select * from database.user_table WHERE user_id-'user';

and

select * from database.user_table WHERE user_id = 'user';

Both seem to work, however, they return a different result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This depends on what the type of `user_id` is.  Assuming that it is a string, then:

```
WHERE user_id = 'user'
```

will return rows where `user_id` is the string `'user'` (or perhaps with capital letters depending on the collations for the database and the column).

When you do:

```
WHERE user_id - 'user'
```

Then two things are happening.  If the expression evaluates to `0` or (`NULL`), then the row is filtered out.  This is equivalent of `WHERE user_id - 'user' <> 0`.

The `-` is a numeric operator, so both values are converted to numbers.  MySQL uses a silent conversion method, where the leading "digits" are converted. So, `'user'` is converted to `0` (no leading digits or numeric type characters).  `'user_id'` will also be converted.  In this case, basically any `user_id` that starts with a digit will pass the test (as well as most that start with a decimal point).

If `user_id` is an integer, then `user_id = 'user_id'` is the same as `user_id = 0`.  And `user_id - 'user'` is the same as `user_id <> 0`.